# JS write HTML <video class"afterglow"> and Link a class

Tags: javascript, html, video-player

I have some problems with this project i have a JS file who is some boostrap modal popu.p and printing a html5 videoplayer ... but the problem is that i cannot link the class for the videoplayer theme. Can you guys help me to find the problem or solution?

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/afterglow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.initialize.js"></script>
```

**JS SCRIPT**

```
var video_wpp = null;
var video = null;
var format = "";
if(obj.filme == undefined || obj.filme == null){
    video_wpp = $("<div class='not_available'>Video not available!</div>");
}
else{
    if(obj.filme.indexOf(".flv") > -1)
    {
        video_wpp = $("<div class='flv-video'></div>");
        video_wpp.attr("id", "flv_"+obj.id);
        format = "flv";
    }
    else if(obj.filme.indexOf(".mp4") > -1)
    {

        video_wpp = $("<div class='mp4-video'></div>");
        video_wpp.css({
            width: "100%"
        });


        video = $('<video controls class="afterglow" oncontextmenu="javascript:return false;" id="myvideo" data-skin="dark" data-autoclose="true">');


        var src = $('<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>');
        src.attr("src", obj.filme);
        src.attr("type", "video/mp4");

        video.append(src);
        video_wpp.append(video);
        format = "mp4";
    }
}
```

The JWPLAYER works he links the class and bring the player , but the afterglow dosent link why? Only shows the standard white html videoplayer

Answer (score 1):

After adding a video element dynamically, afterglow needs to be initialized using `afterglow.init()`. This will happen automatically when the `DOMContentLoad` event is triggered but has to be done manually when adding videos after the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

As you are using jQuery, I assume that your code is bound the this event just like afterglow (which is the default way to work with jQuery), so you'll need to apply this again (f.i. after `video_wpp.append(video);`.

Comment: I tried 

    video.append(src);    
    video_wpp.append(video);
    format = "mp4";
    afterglow.init();
 
I tried  afterglow.init(video); and afterglow.init(myvideo);

Nothing changes still the standard white videoplayer html5

Comment: Please see the discussion in the forums. https://community.afterglowplayer.com/d/78-write-js-html-cant-connect-class